# Using existence of an object in an if statement in Haxe

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, haxe

Can you use an object's existence as the condition of an if statement in Haxe? If so, how?

```
var b : Bullet = collide("bullet", x, y);
if (b) {
  b.destroy();
}
```

I've also tried testing it against the `Null` type, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `if (b != null)` should work

Comment: Herp, derp. Capitalization will be the end of me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As kirilloid mentions in the comments, try checking if `b` is not null:

```
var b : Bullet = collide("bullet", x, y);
if (b != null) {
  b.destroy();
}
```

It was decided for Haxe not to have the `if(b)` syntax for a number of reasons. You can find a discussion on the topic on [Google Groups: Test if exists](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/haxelang/not%2420null/haxelang/ntmHF4BJlnQ/qG7hBTxWJ-4J).

Comment: Pitfall warning: The flexibility of Haxe leads to some peculiar behavior with respect to null.